# How to define HTML's input field when I need to store floating numbers of varying precision?

Tags: html, number-formatting

I need an input form element that can store numbers such as these:

- 4.6050927694997500
- 0.0384623400229826
- -0.0000317620199043
- etc

Currently to be able to enter such a number, HTML spec requires you to set up a step value, like so:

```
<input type="number" step="0.0000000000000001">
```

It feels a little weird for me to define a step value so small with so many zeroes.

Is there a better way to do this?  Should I just be using a `text` field type for my floating numbers instead of the `number`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>Yes, it is good idea</del> You have to use `text` field (it does not have up/down buttons – you can use JS to create them). It is good to use a `pattern` attribute to inform user the input is invalid.

```html
<!-- TRY THIS SNIPPET -->

negative or positive
<input pattern="-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?" value="0">
<hr>

only positive
<input pattern="[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?" value="0">

<hr>

negative or positive supporting "scientific" format (eg. 5.3e-5)
<input pattern="-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?([eE]-?[0-9]+)?" value="0">

<hr>

positive supporting "scientific" format (eg. 5.3e-5)
<input pattern="[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?([eE]-?[0-9]+)?" value="0">

<hr>
Try entering some numbers (5, -5, 5.5, -5.5, -4.556e5, 4.556e5)
```

Also (as in the case of `type=number` field) check it on the server (if it is sent).